# Knockout.js: Function being called on unassigned binding

Tags: knockout.js

It's my first post. 
I'm pretty new to knockout and trying a basic example. 
In below Eg: I am trying to change the **ONLY** labels into Upper case the labels(Last Name and Full Name) not the input text box. So, I've assigned the value of text box initially to a hidden field and from there on manipulating the hidden field. but, at the end input also modified to upper case. any help is much appreciated!!

**My View:**

```
    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    <input style="display:none;" data-bind="value: hdnlastName" />
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName">todo</strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: hdnlastName">todo</strong></p>
    <p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: firstHdnLastName"></strong></p> 
    <button data-bind="click: capitalizeHdnLastName">Click Me!!</button>
```

**View Model:**

```
    function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Gireesh");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("");

    this.hdnlastName = this.lastName;

    this.firstHdnLastName = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.hdnlastName();
    },this);

    this.capitalizeHdnLastName = function(){
    var tempValue = this.hdnlastName();
    return this.hdnlastName(tempValue.toUpperCase());};
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to change Last Name (label) and last Name in Full Name to Upper case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're setting hdnlastName = lastName so both variables are pointing to the same thing. You can't update one without it updating the other. To fix it you need to make hdnlastName its own observable

```
this.hdnlastName = ko.observable("");
```

but then you also need to keep it synchronized with changes to lastName

```
this.lastName.subscribe(function(value){ 
    this.hdnlastName(value);
}, this);
```

example:

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Gireesh");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("");

    this.hdnlastName = ko.observable("");
    this.lastName.subscribe(function(value){ 
        this.hdnlastName(value);
    }, this);

    this.firstHdnLastName = ko.computed(function(){
      return this.firstName() + " " + this.hdnlastName();
    },this);

    this.capitalizeHdnLastName = function(){
      var tempValue = this.hdnlastName();
      this.hdnlastName(tempValue.toUpperCase());
    };
}
  
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    <input style="display:none;" data-bind="value: hdnlastName" />
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName">todo</strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: hdnlastName">todo</strong></p>
    <p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: firstHdnLastName"></strong></p> 
    <button data-bind="click: capitalizeHdnLastName">Click Me!!</button>
```